# How to replicate the behaviour of 'name in a TH splice

Tags: haskell, ghc, template-haskell

Consider this Haskell file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin Test.Inspection.Plugin #-}
module Text (main) where

import Test.Inspection

import Data.Text as T
import Data.Text.Encoding as E
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)

import Language.Haskell.TH

toUpperString :: String -> String
toUpperString = T.unpack . T.toUpper . T.pack

toUpperBytestring :: ByteString -> String
toUpperBytestring = T.unpack . T.toUpper . E.decodeUtf8

do Just n <- lookupValueName "toUpperString"
   inspect $ n `hasNoType` ''T.Text
inspect $ 'toUpperBytestring `hasNoType` ''T.Text

main :: IO ()
main = return ()
```

It uses Template Haskell to define test obligations which are tested by the GHC plugin in inspection-testing.

Under the hood, inspection testing passes a Template Haskell name in an annotation, and converts it to to a Core name using `thNameToGhcName`, and then tries to find this name in the current module.

This works fine if I create a template Haskell name using `'foo`, but it fails if I use `lookupValueName`.

- Why are they different?
- How can I recreate the behavior of `'foo` when I have a string?

(Why do I not just use `'foo`? Because I want to dynamically create obligations, so I have Template Haskell code that defines many such functions and obligations.)

Answer (score 4):

The problem in this case is not so much that the `Name` returned by `'foo` vs. `lookupValueName` is different, but that using `'foo` keeps `foo` alive throughout the compilation of the module, while `lookupValueName "foo"` does not. Then GHC removes the binding of `"foo"` and inspection-testing trips over it.

And indeed removing the export list from the module, which keeps all top-level bindings around, makes the problem go away.

Comment: Any opinios about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964198/plugin-name-lookup-behavior-change-from-ghc-8-4-series?